# What is the difference between “yep” and “yeah”?

Tags: word-meaning, difference, negation, slang

What is the difference caused by using “yep” instead of ”yeah”?

Is it used because “yep” sounds better and not straight like “yeah”? In some situations, it feels like "yes" is better to use than no even though it adds more formal. What is the reason why many use "yep" and "yeah"? When should one use over the other?

What is the difference in meaning among the common words yes, yeah, ya, yep, and yup?

Comment: I think there’s no real difference that can be articulated between the closest ones, like ‘yep’ or ‘yeah’ or ‘ya’, and that what differences there are are highly regional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Yeah", "yeh", "yup", and "yep" are all informal variants of "yes".

In an informal setting (i.e., in casual conversations — talking to your friends, colleagues, and family members), you would be just fine using any of them. Only in a very formal setting, would the use of the informal variants be frowned upon. "Yes" works in any setting, but it may be a bit formal when you are hanging out with your friends. However, "yes" can also be used without sounding formal at all.

> Friend: *You want anything?*
>   You: *Yeah, a beer would be good.*
>   Friend no. 2: *Are you okay man?*
>   You: *Yes brother, I am good now.*

Don't do this (or anything of this sort):

> Question: *Will you be my wife?* or *Do you, X, take Y to be your lawfully wedded wife/husband?*
>   You: *Yep.*

Sometimes, both "yeah" and "yep" can be used when we are trying to be dismissive, or when we don't want to continue the conversation anymore. "Yep" can end a conversation abruptly. "Yeah right" can be downright dismissive.

In a way, "yep" might be preferred if that is all you want to say to someone (i.e., just "yes"); "yeah" allows you to continue your statement.

> ""Yep" has that self-sufficient feel, as if it had a period attached to it. "Yeah", on the other hand, feels like it has a comma attached, inviting me to expand on it. "Yeah, I did it", "yeah, that's right", "yeah, we really should do that" and so on." – RegDwigнt♦ Aug 25 '10 at 19:39
>
> <sup>EL&U: [When is it appropriate to use “Yeah” and “Yep” as variants of the word “Yes”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1954/when-is-it-appropriate-to-use-yeah-and-yep-as-variants-of-the-word-yes#:~:text=Yep.,-https%3A%2F%2Fenglish&text=Yes%20is%20not%20a%20formal,both%20formal%20and%20informal%20contexts.&text=Yep%20is%20used%20when%20it's,used%20in%20the%20other%20cases.)</sup>

"Yeah" and "Yep/Yup" are not interchangeable in all cases.

"Yeah" is used before a negation sometimes ("yep/yup" is not commonly used for this case):

> Yeah, I don't know anything about that.
>   Yeah, I am not sure.
>   Yeah, I've no idea man.
>   **Yeah, but ... (this happens quite frequently)**
>
> "Yeah can also be used in a partial negation [yeah, but] meaning that you are affirming only a portion of the question." — Zoot (ibid.)

"Yeah" is also used as an exclamation (e.g., when your favorite team scores a goal, or when your crush sits beside you — in which case it is internal): Yeaaaahhhhhhhhh!!!!! or Yeeaaassssssssssss!!!

Answer (score 1):

All of these words attempt to represent the sounds made when saying "yes" in a casual way or in a particular dialect.

"Yep" tries to capture the sound made when closing the mouth at the end of the word. You might talk like that if you were a little excited about the thing you were saying yes to.  Yeah, on the other hand doesn't have that sharp closing of the mouth,  suggesting a more relaxed pronunciation, less excitement.

Ya is mostly a dialect. I associate it with an upper class English dialect, which uses expressions like "ohkay-ya?"

It's fine for learners to use "yeah", in casual situations, but stick to "yes" if you're unsure.  Don't bother learning "yep" etc. It's not really a different word, just a sound made when closing the mouth.

Comment: At least in AmE, I would associate "yep" with country folk, particularly those of an older generation.  It's by no means exclusive to that demographic of course, just seems like more common relaxed dialect in farm country than what you'd hear in the big city.